# How can I properly convert a void * value into a CString

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm trying to figure out how to use a void * value, I know that it's previous value (when calling the function) is a CString. Here's an example:

At some point, there's a CString value in this var: **sNumBlue** value can be something like: "000000000000000059841145"

```
pNumBlue = new CString(sNumBlue);
PostMessage (WM_BLUERD,DEF_BLUE_ADD_BLUE,(long)pNumBlue);
```

With that last line of code, It'll send the CString value to another function that receives it as a void*, that function already has a way of handling the void * using a Class, but I can't use the class because it's designed to receive another different value or somethig else that I dont seem to understand, and when I try to use it, an exception appears. Here's that function:

```
LRESULT CDat_color::OnBlueRd(short ColorType, void *pBlueRd )
{
       CString sNumColor;
       CColorRead* pColorRead;
       try{
        pColorRead =  (CColorRead*) pBlueRd;
            sNumColor = pColorRead->GetNumColor();
       {Catch(catch stuff...)
           //here it handles the exception
       }
}
```

This is what I've try so far:

1. I tried to cast it to Cstring like this:

   CString* pMyNum = static_cast(pBlueRd);

But I dont think is correct, I'm doing someting wrong, because when I try to print **pMyNum** value, it displays other stuff and not the desired value.

2. I tried to replicate the CColorRead class and gave it a set and get function. I used the set function to set the sNumBlue value before calling the CDat_color::OnBlueRd. And try to get the value when I'm inside the function OnBlueRd, but the value is NuLL at that point, or it throws an exception when I'm trying to get it.

What can I do to get the value safely?
Thank you all, and I'm sorry if the question is not well edited, I'm asking from my phone, Ill try to fix it from a PC. Feel free to ask me anything related, I'm honestly not a great C++ programmer, I'm learning new things everyday.
Btw I'm using Visual C++ 2006 and MFC framework.
Thanks again

Edit:

This is the message handler:

```
afx_msg LRESULT OnBlueRd(short shErr=0,void *pNum=NULL);
```

Added the MESSAGE_MAP:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CDat_color, CDialog)
    ON_MESSAGE(WM_BLUERD,OnBlueRd)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Comment: When you call `PostMessage`, the handler is not called synchronously. So the caller must not `delete` the CString object. This should be done in the message handler.

Comment: you can try reinterpret_cast<CString*>(pBlueRd). But May I ask you what do you cast to (long) when calling the function ?

Comment: In `OnBlueRd(short ColorType, void *pBlueRd)` is `pBlueRd` supposed to be the same pointer as `pNumBlue` in the code above?

Comment: Where is the deletion of `pNumBlue` from `pNumBlue = new CString(sNumBlue);`?

Comment: @harper I included what I think is the message handler

Comment: @Gojita I honestly don't know what **(long) variable** does, I don't understand it, I thought it'll be the same CString

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes, pBlueRd is supposed to be the same pointer as pNumBlue. Can you give me an example of the deletion? Should I add something else before calling the function?

Comment: @qhart please show the message map entry of `OnBlueRd`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I added the message_map in the post

Comment: BTW: I noticed that `CDat_color` is `CDialog` derived. Is it a modal or a modeless dialog? From where is the `PostMessage` called? This might be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), but to find out, we need more information about the _actual_ problem you're trying to resolve.

Comment: The `PostMessage` is called from CDat_color, is a modeless dialog

Comment: @qhart you write _"The PostMessage is called from CDat_color"_. If you call it from a CDat_color method, why do you need to call `PostMessage` in first place? What triggers the call to `PostMessage`? It's very unclear.

Comment: @Jabberwocky You are right, is another function inside CDat_color that calls it. That other function is a ON_MESSAGE entry aswell, but this one is triggered by a device, specifically when it takes a picture

Comment: Using `PostMessage` within the same dialog instance is most likely not necessary, just call an appropriate function should do the job, but still without seeing the bigger picture context it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `ON_MESSAGE` entries the signature of the function must be this:

```
afx_msg LRESULT OnBlueRd(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

You probably want this:

```
pNumBlue = new CString(sNumBlue);
PostMessage (WM_BLUERD, DEF_BLUE_ADD_BLUE, (LPARAM)pNumBlue);  // LPARAM instead of LONG
```

---

```
LRESULT CDat_color::OnBlueRd(WPARAM wpColorType, LPARAM lpBlueRd)
{
    // wpColorType will contain DEF_BLUE_ADD_BLUE, but it's not used in your code
    CString *pNumBlue = (CString*)lpBlueRd;

    // do whatever needs to be done with the string *pNumBlue

    delete pNumBlue;   // delete it

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't change the entry it has to stay the same. I used the CString *pNumBlue = (CString*)lpBlueRd; 
I tried to format it into another CString like: CString sNroBlue.Format("%s", pNumBlue); but I think is not the correct way to do it

Comment: `CString pNumBlue = (CString)lpBlueRd;` is wrong, `lpBlueRd` is a __pointer__. And you should change the message map entry, your's is simply wrong. Read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/message-map-macros-mfc?view=vs-2017#on_message

Comment: The reason I can't modify it is because it works dealing with other information, I'm adding into those functions something knew. But the way the data getes there is different, that's why I have to try another way of getting that void*. Basically the before calling `OnBlueRd` the value is a CString, but it has to be received by `OnBlueRd` like a void*. The problem is that I can't figure out the correct way to "convert" it

Comment: Sorry, wrong code is wrong code. I can't help if you're not willing to correct it.

Comment: You are probably right, I'll try to fix it in the way you suggested me, and I'll read the documents

Comment: I'm selecting this as the correct answer because it's well documented and it has the necessary logic to work properly as it should be. Thanks to you I managed to do the following: 
I used `CString *pNumBlue = (CString*)pBlueRd;`
Then I declared a `CString aux;` and managed to pass the value to it: `aux.Format("%s", *pNumBlue);` And it work perfectly, all that thanks to you.

Comment: The `Format` is pointless, you can simply write `CString aux = *((CString*)pNumBlue)`, it will do the same thing in a fraction of the time used by `Format`, or you can use `*pNumBlue` directly as long as `delete pNumBlue` has not been done.